# How to *limit* screen resolution on QEMU?

Tags: resolution, qemu

If we have a 800x600 physical display, *its resolution can never be larger than 800x600, no matter what other parts of the system do*.

How to emulate such behavior with QEMU? I can patch the source and recompile if needed.

Rationale: I'm using android-x86 as guest and I can't get it fit my host's physical screen.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get a smaller resolution with these parameters:

> -display sdl -vga none -device virtio-vga,xres=800,yres=600

I can't get android-x86 to work right now and so I can't test if it works, but I had the same problem with a Linux host, the window was too large and I couldn't read the last couple lines of the tty.

After booting I could then change the resolution to a bigger or smaller one, but it never became bigger than 800x600 on its own.

If those parameters doesn't work, maybe you can manage to do it modifying the QEMU VGA bios, like explained [here](https://www.tablix.org/%7Eavian/blog/archives/2013/05/custom_display_resolutions_in_qemu/)  (the link explains how to add resolutions, but removing them should be simpler)

Basically, the instructions are:

- Fetch the source tarball
- Edit the file roms/vgabios/vbetables-gen.c (leaving just the desired resolution)
- Now re-build the VGA BIOS binary image (apt-get install bcc first):
- > $ cd roms/vgabios
- > $ make stdvga-bios
- QEMU's make install will not install the image you just built. Instead, it will use an already built binary they ship with the source. Therefore you have to install it manually:
- > cp VGABIOS-lgpl-latest.stdvga.bin $PREFIX/share/qemu/vgabios-stdvga.bin

Then you'll boot the VM with

> -vga std